# Redmi Note 4 doesn't run apps from Android studio

Tags: android, redmi-device

I recently bought a Xiaomi Redmi Note 4 and I try to use it as device to run an application from Android studio..
The first time, it runs ok, but after that, it crashes and it says that there is a problem with the app and it can't run it. The code is correct!
I become developer and enable USB Debuging and installation through USB, but when I try to enable USB Debuging (security), it pops a message "The device i temporary restricted"... 
The message that pops in my device is that:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: No field mAssets in class Landroid/content/res/MiuiResourcesImpl; (declaration of 'android.content.res.MiuiResourcesImpl' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5431)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1563)
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6195)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:874)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:764)
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: No field mAssets in class Landroid/content/res/MiuiResourcesImpl; (declaration of 'android.content.res.MiuiResourcesImpl' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar)
>       at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.MonkeyPatcher.monkeyPatchExistingResources(MonkeyPatcher.java:442)
>       at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication.onCreate(BootstrapApplication.java:308)
>       at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1025)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5428)
>       ... 8 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: No field mAssets in class Landroid/content/res/MiuiResourcesImpl; (declaration of 'android.content.res.MiuiResourcesImpl' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar)
>       at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Native Method)
>       at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.MonkeyPatcher.monkeyPatchExistingResources(MonkeyPatcher.java:433)
>       ... 11 more

Is there anyone that can help me? Thank you!

Comment: Login to your MIUI account (or create one) and then enable USB Debugging in Developer Options. That should let you run the app.

Comment: I have made it from the minute I bought the phone.. :(

Answer (score 5):

There is a problem with the Redmi Note 4 smartphone.
The following instructions will work with the PC and Mac.

Go to Settings > Additional Settings (under System and Device) > Developer Options

1. Scroll to the bottom of the page and disable *Turn on MIUI optimization*
2. Enable *USB debugging*
3. Enable *Install via USB*
4. Enable *USB Debugging(Security setting)*

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
maybe it will help you.

Additional Settings > Developer Option > there at the bottom just turn off MIUI optimization.

Comment: I forgot.. I have already done that... thanks for help.. any other idea??

Comment: Try




File > Invalidate Caches / Restart

Comment: pfff.... The same... It runs the first time correctly and then it crashes again.. Is there any way to solve it?? or else I have to do this for every change I make... (Thanks again)

Comment: I found a temporary solution, every time before I run it in my device the app, I clean the project.. It works, but it take time..

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. I was not able to enable Install Via USB option, however, I found a solution that actually worked.

Here are the steps to enable it.

1. Install [PlexVPN](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shoplex.plex&hl=en) app on your mobile phone
2. Open PlexVPN then set VPN to China (e.g **China-Shanghai**) and connect
3. Go to Developer Options and enable **Install Via USB** option
4. Enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all of the methods above, but unfortunately, none of it works for me.

The root cause is some defect inside MIUI(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIUI).

To avoid this crash, you need to avoid using these external package.

I used buck build, so I simply disable Exopackage.